# Video connection for Mac Mini M2 to DisplayPort/DVI monitor

Tags: display, video, mac-mini, hdmi

I'm planning to order an M2 Mini and I want to connect it to a Dell U2412M monitor that I already have.

The Mini has HDMI video output, but I believe it can also serve video via Thunderbolt 4.

The monitor has DisplayPort and DVI inputs.

What would be a good way to connect these two devices?

The monitor does not have speakers, so I don't care about running audio.

My only other Mac experience is with a 2013 MacBook Pro, so my hardware/port knowledge is not exactly up to date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would connect the DisplayPort output on your Mac to the DisplayPort input on your monitor. I see no reason to convert to or from HDMI, DVI, Thunderbolt 3 or Thunderbolt 4. The USB-C ports on your Mac can supply DisplayPort output directly from the Mac's graphics hardware.

For example, you could use [this cable](https://www.mycablemart.com/store/cart.php?m=product_detail&p=10155&ad_source=google_usa&gclid=CjwKCAiAioifBhAXEiwApzCztg1TZnKndKUr-3iU0Ax0k8p9ppvmpG9ggnVgjfRZt_ScalF3dvIjBhoCA7IQAvD_BwE).

In your case, you should be looking for cable specifications which equal or exceed the the following.

- Connector A: USB Type C Male
- Connector B: DisplayPort Male
- Apple ALT-MODE Compliant
- DisplayPort v1.1a resolution up to 1920x1200@60HZ

> Note: Apple refers to "USB-C Alt-mode" as "native DisplayPort output over USB‑C",

### References

- [Connect a display to Mac mini](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-mini/connect-a-display-apd8e4fbbb97/mac)
- [Dell<sup>TM</sup> UltraSharp U2412M/U2412MWh Monitor](https://downloads.dell.com/manuals/all-products/esuprt_electronics_accessories/esuprt_electronics_accessories_monitors/dell-u2412m_user%27s-guide_en-us.pdf)
- [Apple Mac mini Specs](https://www.apple.com/mac-mini/specs/)